# available memory when attached to docker container is less than container limit

Tags: memory, docker, out-of-memory

when i start a container like this:

`docker run -d --memory=6g $image`,

`docker stats $container_id` shows that it has a memory limit of 6gb, which is expected.

however, when i connect into that container (`docker exec -it $container_id /bin/bash`), my shell is limited to only 1gb. (which is confirmed by calling `free -m` as well as some testing in allocating objects in python [it fails at around 1gb]).

my question is: *how can i get access to all of the memory available in the container?*

thank you.

Comment: You can't consume more resources that what is available at the OS level. Docker is just a special type of process running on the host machine.

Comment: oh, actually, great call! my host vm is fricking limited to 1gb. i will fix that immediately. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok, in this case, even though `docker stats` was showing that my container had 6gbs, the virtual machine on which docker was running was limited to 1gb. so i changed my virtual machine limitations and solved the problem.